# Why does pip3 -V and sudo pip3 -V show different versions

Tags: pip

Why does pip3 -V and sudo pip3 -V show different versions?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ pip3 -V
pip 18.1 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo pip3 -V
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: There's 2 different paths. Seems you have 2 copies of python3.7 installed.

Comment: What is your version of Linux and how did you install your Python 3.7?

Comment: @GinoMempin Not necessary 2 different Pythons but certainly 2 different `pip`s — one installed with `sudo pip install -U pip`, the other with `pip install -U --user pip`.

Comment: Ah good catch. Not sure why I did that. I'm using a raspberry pi. I uninstalled pip/python from both places, now when I run pip I get ```pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip
-bash: /home/pi/.local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory``` and when I run sudo pip I get ```pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory``` Now I'm I wonder why running pip with or without sudo would point to different locations? I would think both would point to the global version of pip/python?

Comment: Is it better to install pip/python with/without sudo?